# Вывод данных с сата в google spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, json

как сделать чтоб выводились данные с api только если они есть, если нет чтоб ставился 0, для гугл докс, вот кусок кода

```js
  function fData(yourname) {
  var toonJSON = undefined;
  var toonJSON = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://сайт.api" + yourname +"");
  Utilities.sleep(100);  
  return toonJSON.getContentText();
}
function name(yourname) {
  var cache = CacheService.getDocumentCache();
  var toonJSON = fData(yourname);  
  var toon = Utilities.jsonParse(toonJSON); 
  return toon;
}
function inf(toonName) {
  var toon = name(toonName);  
  var toonInfo = [toon.weekly[0].level];
  return toonInfo;
```

я так понимаю код выглядеть должен вроде

```js
function inf(toonName) {
  var toon = name(toonName);
  var info = '0';
  for (var i = 0; i < toon.weekly[i]; i++) {
    info = toon.weekly[i].level;
  }
  return info;
```

но видимо что то пропустил =(

Comment: `"https://сайт.api" + yourname +""`  - тут явно ошибка. Нужен или параметр или слеш. Не может же быть  `хттпc://сайт.apiимя`

Comment: скрипт работает, но выдаёт ошибку если нет данных, скопировал криво, там стоит слеш, ошика в var toonInfo = [toon.weekly[0].level]; если дальше нет данных и заканчивается на [] выдаёт ошибку, а надо чтоб ставило 0 вместо ошибки =)

Comment: В какой именно строке кода - нет данных? Может это просто `if`-oм проверить и отфильтровать?

Comment: не знаю как это сделать =( нашел просто код готовый, вот нужно подправить чтоб не выводил данные если их нет, а ставил 0 вместо данных

Comment: Трассируйте - найдите где именно ошибка (нет данных). Тут трассировка даст ответ гораздо за меньшее время чем ответят на формуме, если ответят.

Comment: вы меня не поняли наверно, всё работает, нужно сделать просто если нет данных, на сайте куда запрос идёт, ставилось 0

Comment: только предпоследнею строчку нужно исправить

Comment: Нашёл  `for( var i=0; i < toon.weekly[i]` - длинна массива всегда `toon.weekly.length`. Вы не указали что в этой строке бьёт ошибку - а это упростило бы вопрос. Т.е. ваш вопрос правильно звучал бы - как получить длинну массива.

Comment: спасибо!!, только заменил ещё i=0 на i=1 вроде всё правильно отображает, надо ещё потестить

Answer (score -1):

Нашёл for( var i=0; i < toon.weekly[i] - длинна массива всегда toon.weekly.length. Вы не указали что в этой строке бьёт ошибку - а это упростило бы вопрос. Т.е. ваш вопрос правильно звучал бы - как получить длинну массива. – nick_n_a вчера

спасибо nick_n_a проблема решена =)

Comment: Уже спрашивали неоднократно ваш вопрос - используйте поиск на сайте ( держу в курсе ) google spreadsheets